# Obout Grid Control

Tags: asp.net, grid, paging, obout

I'm having issues using the Obout grid control after changing pages on the grid. For example, testing one of their examples available for download from their site (aspnet_grouping_initial.aspx) if you change pages on the grid you can no longer expand/collapse the groupings.

The same issue exists in all their grid examples if you try to perform any action after changing a page.

Has anyone figured out how to fix this?

Note it does work on their website but not in the code samples you can download.

I have already emailed their support without a response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. The "aspnet_grouping_initial.aspx" sample works without problems and if you change the page or the page size you can still expand/collapse groups or perform other actions (sorting, etc.). Nobody else reported such problem, so this might be caused from something from your end. What browser are you testing in? Do you get any errors on the client-side after navigating to a different page in the Grid? Are all the resources (scripts, stylesheets, images) loading properly in the browser?